# Regex Match all characters until reach character, but also include last match

Tags: c#, regex, search, preg-match, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to find all Color Hex codes using Regex.

I have this string value for example - `#FF0000FF#0038FFFF#51FF00FF#F400FFFF` and I use this:

```
#.+?(?=#)
```

pattern to match all characters until it reaches `#`, but it stops at the last character, which should be the last match.

[image]

I'm kind of new to this Regex stuff. How could I also get the last match?

Comment: How about `#[0-9A-Fa-f]{8}` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex does not match the last value because your regex (with the positive lookahead `(?=#)`) requires a `#` to appear after an already consumed value, and there is no `#` at the end of the string.

You may use

```
#[^#]+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Zqcp2f/1)

The `[^#]` negated character class matches any char but `#` (`+` means *1 or more occurrences*) and does not require a `#` to appear immediately to the right of the currently matched value.

In C#, you may collect all matches using

```
var result = Regex.Matches(s, @"#[^#]+")
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(x => x.Value)
    .ToList();
```

A more precise pattern you may use is `#[A-Fa-f0-9]{8}`, it matches a `#` and then any 8 hex chars, digits or letters from `a` to `f` and `A` to `F`.

Comment: I wouldn't say flawlessly unless you want it to match `#hello world`

Comment: @UnknownUser Just finished typing. @sln, there is no such input in OP post. Anyway, `#[A-Fa-f0-9]{8}` covers it.

Comment: So you only rely upon a cropped sample? You and that other guy. Just split on # and save the world.

Comment: @sln If you want to split, then it should be `Regex.Split(s, @"(?=#)").Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x))`. It is not that simple as just split with `#` here.

Comment: I personally don't use split, so, no I don't want to split. Thanks for the code but  like I said, I don't use it. But if I did, I'd just split on #. The array elements would either be blank or not.

Answer (score 0):

Don't rely upon any characters after the #, match hex characters and it
will work every time.

`(?i)#[a-f0-9]+`